# R: How to set adjustable width in a barplot?

Tags: r, width, bar-chart

I am trying to automate the creation of bar graphs that I have to use regularly on a changing data set.
Here is an example that demonstates the format of the data. The number of years and months included in the data set is variable:

```
plotdata<-data.frame(c(2014, 2015, 2015), c(5, 5, 6), c("example", "example", "example"), c(0.34, 0.44, 0.52))
names(plotdata)<-c('year', 'month', 'name', 'value')
```

I made a function to create a standard bar graph, which looks like this:

```
bar_month<-function(x){

lbls<-ifelse(plotdata$month==1, paste("January\n", plotdata$year),
      ifelse(plotdata$month==2, paste("February\n", plotdata$year),
      ifelse(plotdata$month==3, paste("March\n", plotdata$year),
      ifelse(plotdata$month==4, paste("April\n", plotdata$year),
      ifelse(plotdata$month==5, paste("May\n", plotdata$year),
      ifelse(plotdata$month==6, paste("June\n", plotdata$year),
      ifelse(plotdata$month==7, paste("July\n", plotdata$year),
      ifelse(plotdata$month==8, paste("August\n", plotdata$year),
      ifelse(plotdata$month==9, paste("September\n", plotdata$year),
      ifelse(plotdata$month==10, paste("October\n", plotdata$year),
      ifelse(plotdata$month==11, paste("November\n", plotdata$year),
      ifelse(plotdata$month==12, paste("December\n", plotdata$year),
NA))))))))))))


maxY=max(na.omit(plotdata$value))
maxX<-length(na.omit(plotdata$month))
title<-paste("Monthly Values",  as.character(unique(na.omit(x$name))))


bar<-barplot(plotdata$value,
    ylim=c(0, maxY),
    xlim=c(0, maxX),
    main=title,
    xlab="Month",
    ylab="Value",
    cex.names=2.5,
    width = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
axis(side=1, labels=lbls, at=bar, las=0, pos=0)
result<-bar
return(result)
}
graph<-bar_month(x)
```

That works fine, with one exception. The width of the bars changes with the amount of months that occur within the data set. If I have only few month in a given data set then I get huge bars, which looks silly. I would like to define a maximum width or an adjustable width of bars depending on the number of values in my data set. Is there any way I could do this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think I have to add, that in the example above I defined the width as 0.5, as I would like to have it. However, in a data set with varying numbers of values, I would have to adjust the width every time, which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `xlim` to a fixed maximum, e.g. `xlim=c(0, 10)` (depending on the maximum number of months in your data set) and set the `width` to `width = rep(0.5,10))`, the bars will always have the same widths.

EDIT:

```
maxWidth <- ifelse(maxX <= 5, 0.1,0.5)
bar<-barplot(plotdata$value,
    ylim=c(0, maxY),
    xlim=c(0, maxX),
    main=title,
    xlab="Month",
    ylab="Value",
    cex.names=2.5,
    width = rep(maxWidth,maxX))
```

Find the optimal threshold in `ifelse(maxX <= 5, 0.1,0.5)`. This may work better.

Comment: That's true it works. Unfortunately, I don't actually know the maximum number of months. Sometimes a survey goes over just a few months, sometimes several years. A more general solution would be great.